# How to convert a JavaScript object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have this object:

```
var json = {
  "alex" : [
    {'count' : 1, 'date': 2},
    {'count' : 2, 'date': 2},
  ],
  "alex" : [
    {'count' : 10, 'date': '1'},
    {'count' : 20, 'date': '10'},
  ],
};
```

How do I convert it to:

```
var arr = [
  {
    name: 'alex',
    data: [[10,1],[20,2]]
  },
  {
    name: 'bob',
    data: [[10,1],[20,2]]
  }
]
```

Comment: That is not JSON. It is a javascript object literal. And an invalid one at that, as you can't have the same property listed twice. That being said, have you made any effort at all to achieve this?

Comment: pass data from php to highcharts {type area and many series} so the way i think is convert php array to json i got format above and it works well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var json = {
  "alex" : [
    {'count' : 1, 'date': 2},
    {'count' : 2, 'date': 2},
  ],
  "bob" : [
    {'count' : 10, 'date': '1'},
    {'count' : 20, 'date': '10'},
  ],
};


var res = Object.keys(json).map(function (el) {
  return {
    name: el,
    data: json[el].map(function (e) {
      return [e.count, e.date]    
    })
  }  
})

console.log(res);
```